# Clear sharedpreferences

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences

I have shared preferences in my app

I want to clear it by tapping a button

How I can do this?

I using Xamarin(c#) for making Android  app

SharedPreferences code

On first activity:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
```

And on Second:

```
    ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
        string product = prefs.GetString ("title","");
        string _weight = prefs.GetString ("weight","");
        string _price = prefs.GetString ("price","");
```

Comment: Nope.  This is Java, I need c# @matthewrdev

Comment: A quick port: `prefs.Edit().Clear().Commit();`

Comment: Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'Android.Content.ISharedPreferencesEditor' (CS0029) 

  Have this Error @matthewrdev

Comment: matthewrdev's code looks correct to me, @Eugene. `.Edit()` returns an `ISharedPreferencesEditor`, then `.Clear()` returns the same object, (`ISharedPreferencesEditor`), then `.Commit()` returns a boolean. How are you trying to use it?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't works? @SimonMᶜKenzie

Answer (score 0):

That's code do this

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
            editor.Clear();
            editor.Commit();
```